# What are the possible generalizations of trees?

Tags: graph-theory

A tree is a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. It is easy to note that tree has no cycle.

I am looking for the example of graphs which are the generalizations of the trees.

**Question :** What are the possible generalizations of tree?

Comment: The most obvious generalization is [forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest), i.e., graphs whose connected components are trees.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott  Thanks I am looking for more such examples. I am looking for connected graphs.

Comment: @I_wil_break_youas It is not clear what you are asking. One could say that a graph is a generalization of a tree and that would, technically speaking, answer your question.

Comment: Trees are planar graphs. Trees are bipartite graphs. Trees are perfect graphs. So those are all possible generalizations of trees. It might help if you told us what you want it for.

Comment: @I_wil_break_youas  Why did you delete the question about [the bipartite graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720894/inequality-involving-maximal-matching-in-a-directed-bipartite-graph/3720929#3720929) after getting an answer?  This behavior is frown upon in this website.  Please restore it.